# how do i transfer a alias name from one query to another?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How do i save an alias name of one table in SQL (bigquery) to use in later queries?. there must be a way to avoid having to write the entire table name for each query.  in this example ,id like to save the nameof the table as Citibike_station. how can i transfer this alias name to use in a different query?

`FROM` bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations` AS citibike_stations

not sure exactly what to do here. I've tired researching it online but i haven't found a satisfactory answer

Answer (score 0):

ex:

"select column from table t"

From now on, you can reference "t" on your query and it will be interpreted as the table you are looking for.

"AS" should still be used for columns

Answer (score 0):

For *table alias visibility*, you can refer to [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#alias_visibility).

> FROM clause aliases are not visible to subqueries in the same FROM clause.

But if you want to use a short alias instead of *fully qualified table name*,
you might consider **CTE** (common table expression, or somtimes called as *named subquery*) or a **temp table** like below. (I don't prefer though)

```sql
WITH citibike_stations AS (
  SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations`
),
subquery_1 AS (
  SELECT * FROM citibike_stations
),
subquery_2 AS (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS dummy
  ) CROSS JOIN citibike_stations
)
SELECT * FROM subquery_2 LIMIT 10;
```

For multiple *select* statements,

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE citibike_stations AS
SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations`;

-- now you can use a shorthand table name instead of FQTN.

SELECT * FROM citibike_stations LIMIT 1;

SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 1 AS dummy
) CROSS JOIN citibike_stations LIMIT 1;
```